# localhost :: cross domain ajax

Tags: ajax, localhost

Is there any way to tell your localhost that it can do cross domain ajax calls?

I need this for my testing.

If it is a browser specific issue i am using google chrome.

Cheers.

Comment: FYI the accepted answer is a bit outdated, thought you might like to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's absolutely not possible. If it could be disabled by the user then it would be the main target for anyone with nefarious or dubious intent, and as prone as any other software to exploitation. It's difficult enough making secure software, without painting on even more attractive targets.

The only way to implement cross-domain Ajax is to route requests via a server-side script.

It's worth mentioning that there is, perhaps, a glimmer of hope for you: in the form of [cross-window messaging with HTML 5 postMessage](http://ajaxian.com/archives/cross-window-messaging-with-html-5-postmessage)

It's probably worth your having a read of some related (though I'm not sure they're duplicate) questions:

- [Why the cross-domain Ajax is a security concern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466737/why-is-cross-domain-ajax-a-security-concern)
- [Firefox Cross Domain Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411039/firefox-cross-domain-request)

---

**Edited** in response to comment:

> So you mean have a script that takes the params, adds them to the request, sends it out, and then echos out the response object?

Essentially yes. In picture format:

```
client  |--------------> | server side |----------------------->  | remote domain
browser | <----ajax------|   script    | <------------------------|--/
```

---

**Edited** to add that this is now sort of possible, using Cross-Origin Resource Sharing ([CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)); in which a script from one domain sends an Origin HTTP header stating the URL of the page, and the server can respond (if configured to do so) with either an error (if CORS is disabled, or unsupported) or with any requested data.

References:

- [CORS compatibility](http://caniuse.com/cors).
- [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, at the W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).
- [Enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://enable-cors.org/).

Comment: So you mean have a script that takes the params, adds them to the request,

sends it out,
and then echos out the response object?

Answer (score 26):

It's very possible. Let's start with a dev browser.

**Step 1:** Download Chromium

Windows -- http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium

Mac -- http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/36244/chromium/

There should be a build ready to go, but these locations change over time. So if these end up with 404's do a Google search for Windows Chromium Download and you'll find it.

**Step 2:** Then run the executable with this flag after it. `--disable-web-security`

Windows -- Create a shortcut to the executable and tag this in the Properties. Or run from [CMD].

Mac -- Open up a terminal and run this straight from there with the flag.

And, you should be good to go. I also setup a quick Apache service and run through a 127.0.0.1 configured domain, but localhost should be just fine. Here's proof.

[image: Cross-domain security block disabled]

I hope this helps you!