# angularJS $http.Post not working: Failed to load resource: Request header field 0 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, xmlhttprequest, mongohq

I'm using $http to post some data to my data base.
[Here](http://docs.mongohq.com/mongohq-api-beta/documents.html) is the documentation of the database. 
I use it on my terminal and it works.

Here's the error message I got from Safari's console:

1)Failed to load resource: Request header field 0 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. (seems to be sensed by the database)

2)XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://beta-api.mongohq.com/mongo/MyDId/myDatabse/collections/myCollection/documents. Request header field 0 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

Here's my code:

```
factory.sendUrlTag = function(data){
        d = '{"document" : {"url_URL":"53738eef9256a31f4fdf6bf8","tag_Tag":"537375fc9256a31f4fdf6bf3"} }'

        return $http({
        url: 'https://beta-api.mongohq.com/mongo/MyDId/myDatabse/collections/myCollection/documents',
        method: "POST",
        data: d,
        headers: [
             {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'},
                  {'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'},
            {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                {'Authorization' : 'api-key MyKey'}
                 ]
    })
    }

    return factory;
};
```

I didn't have " {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'},
                      {'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'}," before, but I did some research after I got the error and added these. But it's still not working.

I do $http.get() in my app to the same database and it works.

This thing is driving me nuts....
Please help!
Thank you all! :)

Answer (score 0):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and friends are **response** headers, not request headers. It wouldn't make sense if Bob was responsible for granting Bob permission to Alice's system.

The server (`https://beta-api.mongohq.com/mongo/MyDId/myDatabse/collections/myCollection/documents`) has to send them, not the client.

Since you are making a cross-origin `POST` request, the server also needs to be able to respond to a pre-flight `OPTIONS` request.

Comment: Why my POST will be a cross-origin POST request? I don't know what's a cross-origin POST request but is there anyway I could fix it?

Comment: Because you are posting to `https://beta-api.mongohq.com/mongo/MyDId/myDatabse/collections/myCollection/documents` from an HTML document which is not hosted on `https://beta-api.mongohq.com/`

Comment: Is there anyway to get around this issue? I could post it from my terminal. :/ I'm also using web2py as backend and using it to post data to the database and that works, but web2py isn't using $http. Is it because I use $http so it's "from an HTML document"? Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Comment: Web2Py appears to serve a JavaScript laden HTML document to a browser. The code you have in the question looks like JavaScript (which, combined with the error message) suggests it runs on the client, and not server side Python.

Comment: yes, my app use both web2py and angular.js. data directly submit by users go through web2py, and it's working. I'm trying to use angular to submit some data, and this part not working yet. thank you!

Comment: Presumably, it sets appropriate CORS headers. or maybe `$http.get` falls over to JSONP and the database supports it. Look at the traffic in your Net tab of your developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

I found some way maybe able to get around the issue:
Use [this](http://www.ivivelabs.com/blog/fix-cross-domain-ajax-request-angularjs-cors/) and [here](http://www.corsproxy.com) to get around the cross origin origin issue.
And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849200/localhost-cross-domain-ajax) to get around the localhost

It may work.

Another relative [post](http://orcaman.blogspot.com/2013/07/cross-origin-http-with-angular-js.html).